# Can I test an installed app with local data with appium and perl?

Tags: android, macos, perl, appium

I've been using selenium for sometime and now I'd like to try testing an app installed in my phone. So far I've done the following:

- I installed appium for mac and I clicked on run.
- I installed adb.
- "abd devices" detects my phone
- Installed perl libraries for appium.
- I installed an app called apk analyzer to get the app's manifest and read activities names and package names.

I wrote the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Appium;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Waiter;

print "starting script:\n";

my $appium = Appium->new(caps => {
        'remote_server_address' => '0.0.0.0',
        'port' => 4723,
        'platformName' => 'Android',
        'platformVersion' => '6.0.1',
        'deviceName' => 'my device',
        'appPackage' => 'app package',
        'appActivity' => 'activity path',
    });

$appium->launch_app();
sleep(10);
my $element = $appium->find_element('element', 'xpath');
$element->tap();

$appium->quit;
```

With the paths and names that are working for my app and phone...

Well, when I execute it, it opens the app but it seems like it opens a new installation of the app, for example if I the app has a log in step and then you have some data stored there, the appium execution doesn't have those data stored.

Is this the normal behavior of appium or is it possible to test over an installation with saved data?

As an example of what I would like to do:
-I have an agenda with events in different days. I've saved those events over time manually but the app doesn't support an export function..
-I would like to open the app with appium and iterate over the days saving the text.
-If the app that appium opens is a new installation I can't get the data.